# Spring boot test not using overridden bean in test in spite of marking @Primary

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

We have a bean CompanyProcessor.
In spring boot integration test, we want to test an exception scenario when a method in this bean throws Exception.

Therefore we have created an overriding bean TestCompanyProcessor which extends CompanyProcessor.
TestCompanyProcessor is marked @Primary. When we run just this test class, the test runs fine and the overridden bean is used as expected.

But then this test class is run with several other test classes together, each marked as @SpringBootTest, we see that this test fails at first instance as instead of using the overridden bean, it uses this original bean. We have automatic retries on failure for upto 3 retries. On the second or third retry, it somehow finds the correct overridden primary bean and the test passes.

Is there any reason, why it finds the original bean at first instance and then finds the correct overridden bean on subsequent retries when run alongside several other test classes.

The overriden bean is defined as follows.

```
@Primary
@Component
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${test.company.processor}' == 'true'")
class TestCompanyProcessor
```

and on the test class we have

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"test.company.processor=true"})
class TestCompanyProcessorTest {

}
```

P.S.
we saw the same behaviour when we used @Mockbean annotation

Answer (score 1):

You sees this behaviour probably if you have multiple Spring tests that share the same context.
Spring is caching your test application context between tests. This is the default behaviour as the instanciation of the objects in a spring context may take some time.

If you have different beans in different tests you should mark tests that change the ApplicationContext (like the TestCompanyProcessorTest class) with an @DirtiesContext annotation.

Further info on caching:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing-ctx-management
DirtiesContext example:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext

Comment: Thanks, earlier we had DirtiesContext on many tests but they were making the tests very slow , but will try this solution of adding @DirtiesContext to only those tests which change context and see how it goes.

Comment: we had a similar problem. You have multiple options you can investigate. you could look whether you really need a full Spring context. Sometimes you just need JUnit for your tests and set up necessary dependencies by yourself (setter, constructor injection). or in some cases you dont need a fully context (no inmemory db saves a lot of time) and define a leaner context for a set of spring tests.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not sure why but DirtiesContext has not helped. It seems according to what you suggested, we should not load the entire context for each test class, but just added specific beans that are needed for that test. Can be a bit risky as we are testing on a different setup to the production code setup. But may need to do this if this is the only option.